# Typing warnings on Django HttpRequest GET param retrieval in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, python-typing

I currently encounter a warning in PyCharm when I try to retrieve a value from the GET dictionary of the Django HttpRequest object. I have always used the code below but I am trying to add type checks in my source code.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

def parse_request(request: HttpRequest):
    request.GET.get('mykey')
```

Warning: Parameter 'key' unfilled

[image]

I am using

- Python 3.9.6
- Django 3.2.4
- PyCharm 2021.1

Comment: This is because pylint can not "understand" that `request.GET` is not the `MultiValueDict` *class*, but a `MultiValueDict` *value*. The business version of PyCharm has extra tools to help developing Django webapplications, and one can use [`pylint-django`](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django) to run a pylint that "better understands" Django.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have PyCharm Professional

Comment: normally you can enable Django support: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html

Comment: I confirm that Django support is enabled for my project.